# How to change button back to its original state

Tags: swift

I'm currently working through one of Angela Yu's udemy courses in which one has to develop a working xylophone app.
The final aim was that the buttons (red, blue, green etc.) should change their opacity while pressed, as in the following code:

```
 @IBAction func noteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        sender.alpha = 0.5
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                sender.alpha = 1
        }
```

Is there a possibility to not only change the opacity but also the background color as a whole -  e.g. grey (pressed) - back to its original color - after the delay?
I guess you'd have to store the button's original background color somehow but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way would be to set the backgroundColor like so:

```
sender.backgroundColor = .white
```

You could also override the isHighlighted function if you are working with a UIButton class that you overrode. like so

```
override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
         backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? .black :.white
    }
 }
```

Obviously this would have to have to be overridden in a child class of UIButton.

you can store the original in a variable like this

```
 @IBAction func noteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    playSound(soundName: sender.currentTitle!)
    let oldColor = sender.backgroundColor

    sender.alpha = 0.5
    sender.backgroundColor = .white

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            sender.alpha = 1
            sender.backgroundColor = oldColor
    }
```

Comment: `let oldColor = sender.backgroundColor` just gets the current color of the button... if you press it again, this will be `.white`

Comment: Well it gives you whatever the current color of the button is. so If you press it within the 0.2 second window then, yeah, it'll be white.  The right way to do this though is to utilize the isHighlighted function mentioned in my above post.  If you need to do it as the original post showed then your best bet is to define the original button color somewhere outside of the function such as in a nib file or plist somewhere and then access it and set it to the oldColor variable written above.